# Within a class-free, purely function-based, extending type system how does one emulate the invocation of a super method (not the super() call itself)?

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, super, extends

I wish to call the parent function (without super) instead of the inherited child function. What options do I have without using ES classes?

```
    function Queue() {
      this.items = [];
      this.enqueue = function enqueue(item) {
        this.items.push(item);
        return item;
      }
    }
    
    function AsyncQueue() {
      Queue.call(this);
      this.awaiters = new Queue();
    
      this.enqueue = function enqueue(item) {
        const awaiter = this.awaiters.dequeue();
        if (awaiter !== undefined) {
          setImmediate(() => {
            awaiter(item);
          });
        } else {
          super.enqueue(item);
        }
        return item;
      }
    }

AsyncQueue.prototype = Object.create(Queue.prototype);
AsyncQueue.prototype.constructor = AsyncQueue;
```

Comment: why don't you want to use classes, this is what they were made for

Comment: Avoiding it that is all. bad me. but i definitely need help here.

Comment: @Gary ... Does the OP still participate in this thread?

Comment: @Gary ... From all the provided answers / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

The OP after already having mastered the `Queue` super-call within the `AsyncQueue` subtype constructor ...

```
Queue.call(this);
```

... needs to save the later to be used `super.enqueue` reference by assigning a bound version of it before reassigning / overwriting / shadowing it with the subtype's own `enqueue`  implementation ...

```
const superEnqueue = this.enqueue.bind(this);

this.enqueue = function enqueue (item) {
  // ...
}
```

The next provided example code does this in addition to some other small suggested improvements ...

```js
function Queue() {
  // kind of "private class field" assured by local scope.
  const items = [];

  // privileged (thus non prototypal) methods
  // with access capability via local scope.
  this.dequeue = function dequeue (item) {
    return items.shift(item);
  }
  this.enqueue = function enqueue (item) {
    items.push(item);
    return item;
  }
}

function AsyncQueue() {
  // super call.
  Queue.call(this);

  // save/keep the initial `super.enqueue` reference by binding it.
  const superEnqueue = this.enqueue.bind(this);

  this.awaiters = new Queue; 

  // overwrite/shadow the initial `super.enqueue` reference.
  this.enqueue = function enqueue (item) {

    const awaiter = this.awaiters.dequeue();
    // if (awaiter !== undefined) {

    // - one does want to know whether
    //   `awaiter` is a function since
    //   it is going to be invoked.
    if ('function' === typeof awaiter) {

      // setImmediate(() => awaiter(item));

      // - one does want to use a somewhat
      //   similar but standardized way.
      setTimeout(awaiter, 0, item);
    } else {
      // super.enqueue(item);

      // forwarding by using the above's hand-nitted super-delegation.
      superEnqueue(item);
    }
    return item;
  }
}
AsyncQueue.prototype = Object.create(Queue.prototype);
AsyncQueue.prototype.constructor = AsyncQueue;

const asyncQueue = new AsyncQueue;

console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('the')   // the
);
console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('quick') // quick
);
console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('brown') // brown
);
console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('fox')   // fox
);
console.log(
  '- dequeue ...',
  asyncQueue.dequeue()        // the
);
console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('jumps') // jumps
);
console.log(
  '- dequeue ...',
  asyncQueue.dequeue()        // quick
);

console.log(
  '+ + awaiters enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.awaiters .enqueue(
    (...args) => console.log({ args })        
  )                           // (...args) => console.log({ args })
);
console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('over')  // over
);
console.log(
  '- dequeue ...',
  asyncQueue.dequeue()        // brown
);
// async, timeout based, logging { "args": ["over"] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comparing the above implementation and the next provided one which uses class syntax and considering some comments from above ...

> *"why don't you want to use classes, this is what they were made for"* – Xiduzo Nov 27 at 16:00
>
> > *"Avoiding it that is all. bad me. but i definitely need help here."* – Gary Nov 27 at 16:46"

... the questions remains ... **"What is the reason for the OP being willing to sacrifice the much more convenient and safer way of subtyping / sub-classing?"**

```js
class Queue {
  // real private class field ...
  #items = [];

  // ... but prototypal methods.
  dequeue(item) {
    return this.#items.shift(item);
  }
  enqueue(item) {
    this.#items.push(item);
    return item;
  }
}

// a more convenient and safer subtyping / sub-classing.
class AsyncQueue extends Queue {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.awaiters = new Queue;
  }
  // prototypal method again.
  enqueue(item) {
    const awaiter = this.awaiters.dequeue();

    if ('function' === typeof awaiter) {

      setTimeout(awaiter, 0, item);
    } else {
      super.enqueue(item);
    }
    return item;
  }
}
const asyncQueue = new AsyncQueue;

console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('the')   // the
);
console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('quick') // quick
);
console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('brown') // brown
);
console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('fox')   // fox
);
console.log(
  '- dequeue ...',
  asyncQueue.dequeue()        // the
);
console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('jumps') // jumps
);
console.log(
  '- dequeue ...',
  asyncQueue.dequeue()        // quick
);

console.log(
  '+ + awaiters enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.awaiters .enqueue(
    (...args) => console.log({ args })        
  )                           // (...args) => console.log({ args })
);
console.log(
  '+ enqueue ...',
  asyncQueue.enqueue('over')  // over
);
console.log(
  '- dequeue ...',
  asyncQueue.dequeue()        // brown
);
// async, timeout based, logging { "args": ["over"] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your methods on the prototype where they belong. Then you can [directly call the parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67879506/1048572):

```
function Queue() {
  this.items = [];
}
Queue.prototype.enqueue = function enqueue(item) {
  this.items.push(item);
  return item;
};

function AsyncQueue() {
  Queue.call(this);
  this.awaiters = new Queue();
}

AsyncQueue.prototype = Object.create(Queue.prototype);
AsyncQueue.prototype.constructor = AsyncQueue;
AsyncQueue.prototype.enqueue = function enqueue(item) {
  const awaiter = this.awaiters.dequeue();
  if (awaiter !== undefined) {
    setImmediate(() => {
      awaiter(item);
    });
  } else {
    Queue.prototype.enqueue.call(this, item);
  }
  return item;
};
```